# Как изменить цвет модального окна SweetAlert'a?

Tags: javascript

В доках я не нашел информации как это сделать. Возможно плохо искал я.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) изменить цвет можно через CSS:

```
.sweet-alert { background-color: #e2e2e2; }
```

или через Jquery:

```
$(".sweet-alert").css('background-color', '#e2e2e2');
```

**UPDATE**

В [SweetAlert2](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) просто используйте параметр `background`

```js
  $('#btn1').on('click', function() {
    swal({
      title: 'SweetAlert2!',
      background: '#f00',
      text: 'Привет!'});
  });
```

```css
div {
  margin:50px;
}
button {
  padding:15px; font-size: 14px; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/5.3.1/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sweetalert2/5.3.1/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button id="btn1">Жми!</button>
</div>
```